ExoPlayer Playback Error: "Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc. ExoPlayer MediaCodecVideoRenderer Error
I'm encountering the following errors while using Video Player in the Flutter App.
ExoPlayer with the MediaCodecVideoRenderer. The app fails to initialize the decoder with the following error message: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(4, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, 3436400, null, [1280, 720, -1.0], [-1, -1]). Additionally, the log shows MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException, Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, error 0xfffffff4 (NO_MEMORY), and similar messages.
How can I troubleshoot and resolve these errors?
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):       ... 11 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24315): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24315):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(4, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, 3436400, null, [1280, 720, -1.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:578)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24315):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)


Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(4, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, 3436400, null, [1280, 720, -1.0], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1012)


E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315): Video codec error
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(4, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, 3436400, null, [1280, 720, -1.0], [-1, -1])
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1012)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:536)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1444)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:945)


W/MediaCodec-JNI(24315): done releasing MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec().
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315): Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315):   android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, error 0xfffffff4 (NO_MEMORY)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315):       at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1999)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315):       at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1977)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315):       at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1947)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(24315):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:95)
W/MediaCodecRende



I/ACodec  (24315):  [] Now uninitialized
I/ACodec  (24315): [] onAllocateComponent
I/OMXClient(24315): IOmx service obtained
E/ACodec  (24315): Unable to instantiate codec 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc' with err 0xfffffff4.
E/ACodec  (24315): signalError(omxError 0xfffffff4, internalError -12)
E/MediaCodec(24315): Codec reported err 0xfffffff4/NO_MEMORY, actionCode 0, while in state 1/INITIALIZING
D/MediaCodec(24315): flushMediametrics
W/MediaCodec-JNI(24315): try to release MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec()...
W/MediaCodec-JNI(24315): done releasing MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec().


